# Subscribing to an AWS SNS or SQS Topic from .NET web app

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, publish-subscribe, amazon-sns

I have a .NET Core API (#API-1) that updates records in a SQL Database. Then I have another .NET Core API (#API-2) in auto-scaling mode which has an in-memory copy of those records.
I want to publish an event from #API-1 to say that a record was updated so that #API-2 instances can subscribe to that event in order to refresh their local data.
I have done this in Azure using a ServiceBus Topic and subscribing to that Topic from all #API-2 instances.

How can I achieve this in AWS?

Comment: Amazon provides a pub/sub service SNS: https://aws.amazon.com/sns/. I think you can use the fanout feature for your project: https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/send-fanout-event-notifications/

Comment: @Sebastian, So you are saying that #API-1 will publish an event to an SNS-Topic and then I would have one (1) SQS queue for each #API-2 instance, subscribed to that Topic,  right?

Comment: Exactly. You could create and remove the instances with every start/stop of an API#2 instance. As an alternative, you can use the pub/sub functionality of [**Redis**](https://aws.amazon.com/redis/). I first did not think about that but the latter is the solution that I would prefer on your usecase because you don't have to manage all the SQS quees.